# Key responder not responding

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm trying to implement a feature where when I press space bar a timer is toggled. The spacebar is unfortunately non responsive and I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Any help is very appreciated!

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Life extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public static final int SIZE = 15; // map dimension
    public static final int CELL_SIZE = 25; //size of cells
    public static final int UPDATE = 1000; //rate of updating

    public char[][] map; // current values of map
    public char[][]temp_map; // store changes while calculating


    //constructor
    public Life() {
        map = new char[SIZE][SIZE];
        temp_map = new char[SIZE][SIZE];

        //to hear key events
        KeyResponder key = new KeyResponder();
        addKeyListener(new KeyResponder());
        setFocusable(true);



    }

    // Inner class for responding to key events
    private class KeyResponder extends KeyAdapter {

        // Method that runs whenever a key is pressed
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                    System.out.println("test");
                    pause();
                    break;


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you ensured that the panel has the focus?

Comment: Ah, yes, the wonderful world of "why doesn't my `KeyListener` work".  Okay.  `KeyListener` is a fickle mistress and she likes a lot of attention.  In order to be able to respond to a key stroke, the component the `KeyListener` is registered to must both be focusable AND have focus, which makes it kind of messy.  A better all round solution is to use a the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which has been designed to solve this very issue